# Could Not install managed package with quickaction which implements force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, aura, feature-activation

Getting the following when trying to install a managed package which has quick action which implements force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader interface.

> You can only create Lightning Component Quick Actions for Component Bundles containing a component that implements force:lightningQuickAction and has no required attributes without a default value.

Answer (score 2):

So, this isn't a solution (yet) but clarification of the issue and steps to replicate it. I also have a case open with Salesforce support on this so will update if/when I get an answer.

I have seen this error cropping up in a few places now;

- whilst installing a package (as OP),
- whilst trying to upload a package with a force:lightningQuickAction in and,
- whilst trying to add a force:lightningQuickAction component trying to a custom action

I believe that it is changing the version number on the component that causes the issue. I can reliable generate the error message by following these steps;

1. Create a new Lightning Component, no interfaces.
2. Set the Bundle Version Setting to 37.
3. Add the `force:lightningQuickAction` interface to the component and save it (interesting you can save this when the component is v37, despite it being introduced in v38).
4. Set the Bundle Version Setting to 38.
5. Create a custom action on an object;

   - Action Type: Lightning Component
   - Lightning Component: set it to the one you just created
   - Any Label and Name
6. Saving this custom action will give you the error message.

Interestingly in this variety of the error it changes a few things on the page too; the Lightning Component name becomes an Id and the label for the dropdown changes to Visualforce Page.

I have managed to create the same error when uploading a package by having a component on a custom action and in a package before changing the version of the component. Then try to upload. I can't quite yet figure out how to get the third variety where is throws the error on package install. That said I do believe them all to be related.

I have raised a case with premier support and am waiting on an answer, or at the minute even acknowledgement that it is an issue. Any further information or cases that people have would be great in helping to get this sorted. Or indeed if anyone has a fix that would be even more magical.

Comment: Did you got any response back from Support on this? Is this a known issue or if there is a workaround to it?

Comment: It's been escalated to R&D who are investigating it. I'll add updates as I get them.

Comment: This is now registered as a known issue https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000ei4BQAQ